# Magento2 - Child Theme CSS location

Tags: magento2, css, parent-child-theme

i am struggling to find the information i want regarding the location and method by which magento2 child themes inherit the custom css stylesheet. From my limited understanding of inheritance in magento2 i believe the child theme's custom.css location should mirror that of the parents theme. But will this replace the parent theme css or simply add the child theme's css at a higher priority?

Comment: If you use magento's blank or luma theme as parent theme then I would recommend to extend the parent themes less files via _extend.less file. <magento-root>/app/design/<Vendor>/<theme>/web/css/source/_extend.less here you can overwrite the parent. That is the simplest solution I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your css custom code in _theme.less
location file `app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/web/css/source/_theme.less`

Example you extend blank theme 
Add your css add last in head tag of file `default_head_blocks.xml`

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    // Original load
    <css src="css/styles-m.css"/>
    <css src="css/styles-l.css" media="screen and (min-width: 768px)"/>
    <css src="css/print.css" media="print"/>

    <!-- Add your own CSS files here -->
    <css src="css/dropkick.css" />
    <css src="css/your-styles.css" />
</head>
```

Add custom css in scope Magento_Module
`app/design/frontend/Vendor/yourthemename/Magento_Catalog/web/css/source/_extend.less`

```
& when (@media-common = true) {
  \\ Extend catalog module styles 
  \\ Use your css code here
}
```